# Calculating the approximation of sin(x) using 20 terms

Tags: java

I'm trying to evaluate the approximation of sin of 1.89 using a Taylor approximation. I compared the output to the value from Math.sin(x); however, after about 14 terms my value deviates quite largely and becomes erroneous. I tried the approximation for a smaller value of x ( <0.5), and the values match.

I'm just trying to figure out why Java, using sublime and being complied via bash on Mac OSx deviates from the true output.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double x = 1.89;
        double sinx = 0;
        int n = 20;
        int countOdd = 1;
        int counter = 1;
        int result = 0;
        int value = 0;

        while (countOdd <= n) {
            if (counter%2 != 0) {
            // Even term odd number
                if (countOdd%2 == 0) {
                    sinx = sinx - (Math.pow(x,counter)/(double)factorial(counter));
                    System.out.println(" counter even odd term  = " + countOdd);
                    countOdd++;
                    System.out.println(" sinx  = " + sinx);
                }
                // Odd term odd number
                else {
                    sinx = sinx + (Math.pow(x,counter)/(double)factorial(counter));
                    System.out.println(" counter odd odd term  = " + countOdd);
                    countOdd++;
                    System.out.println(" sinx  = " + sinx);
                }
            }
            // Update the result and reset the value
            //sinx = sinx + value;
            //value = 0;
            System.out.println(" counter  = " + counter);
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println(" sinx  = " + sinx);
        System.out.println(" sinx from math library = " + Math.sin(x));
    }

    /** calcutes and returns  n! 
    @param n : a positive integer number
    @return n!
    */
    public static int factorial(int n)
    {
        // your code goes here
        int result = 1; // if n = 0, while loop is by passed and 0 is returned
        while (n >= 1) {
            result = result * (n);
            n--;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try printing out the result of your `factorial` function for various values of `n`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, thanks for the suggestion I'll run a loop and compare to see if the function works as expected, I tried a single point value and stopped there initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is here:

```
public static int factorial(int n) {
    int result = 1;
    while (n >= 1) {
        result = result * (n);
        n--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

you are not considering the fact that factorial converges very fast generating an overflow (some results are negative numbers then)

you can verify that beh. splitting a little the code where factorial returned value is used:

```
    while (countOdd <= n) {

        if (counter % 2 != 0) {
            // Even term odd number
            if (countOdd % 2 == 0) {
                int factorial = factorial(counter);
                System.out.println("factorial: " + factorial);
                sinx = sinx - (Math.pow(x, counter) / factorial);
                System.out.println(" counter even odd term  = " + countOdd);
                countOdd++;
                System.out.println(" sinx  = " + sinx);
            }
            // Odd term odd number
            else {
                int factorial = factorial(counter);
                System.out.println("factorial: " + factorial);
                sinx = sinx + (Math.pow(x, counter) / factorial);
                System.out.println(" counter odd odd term  = " + countOdd);
                countOdd++;
                System.out.println(" sinx  = " + sinx);
            }
        }
```

as you will note, the output will produce negative values which are distroying the numeric approximation you want to achieve

```
 ...
 counter even odd term  = 10
 sinx  = 0.9476740866450655
 counter  = 19
 counter  = 20
 factorial: -1195114496
```

Comment: Much appreciated, changed the type to a double and the values work without the overflow! Will mark as solution in 5 minutes and thanks.

Comment: still consider the fact that factorial never produces a decimal number, so a double is not required....

Comment: Fair point, I just refreshed my memory on the primitive data types and chose long. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double` and `int` for large numerical calculations like factorial and power.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I wasn't familiar with the BigDecimal type.